# Generating ordered permutations of a given string

Tags: java, android

Given a sentence like "one two three four" how would I iterate the List of words in ordered permutation?

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
"one"
"one two"
"one two three"
"one two three four"
"two"
"two three"
"two three four"
"three"
"three four"
"four"
```

I've split the words using space delimiter but cannot work out a method to iterate all the combinations with words kept in current order.

```
  List<String> product_words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(productname.split(" ")));
  for (int x = 0; x < product_words.size(); x++) { 
        //stuck here
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This reeks of homework.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner and????

Comment: I'm 52 years so I doubt it!

Comment: Doesn't fit your exact purposes, but it'd be easy enough to modify http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html

Comment: Note: "irritate" means to annoy someone; I think you meant "iterate".  I've edited it.

Comment: Do you want `"one three"` and `"two four"` to appear in the output?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a double `for` loop, and make sure to start the inner loop at the index of the outer loop (that will omit "one", after you've gone through all of its permutations).

```
ArrayList<String> product_words = new ArrayList<String>();
product_words.add("one");
product_words.add("two");
product_words.add("three");
product_words.add("four");

for (int i = 0; i < product_words.size(); i++) {
    String s = "";
    for (int j = i; j < product_words.size(); j++)  {
        s += product_words.get(j);
        s += " ";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```