# Stopping a for loop without using break

Tags: java, substring

I'm trying to write a program that prints all substrings of entered string. For example if user enter "rum" the output will be this:

```
r
u
m
ru
um
rum
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AllSubStrings
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String str = in.next();
    String sub = "";

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int a=0; a<str.length() ; a++)
        {
            if(i+a+1>str.length())break;
            sub = str.substring(a,i+a+1);
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This program works perfectly but since we didn't learn how to use "break" in classes, i'm looking for something different. Any idea apart from "break" are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about trying to add a break statement?  You seem to know what it does so give it a try.

Comment: Helpful link: [Generating ordered permutations of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143485/generating-ordered-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two conditions in the `for` loop

```
for(int a = 0; a < str.length() && i + a < str.length(); a++)
{
    sub = str.substring(a,i+a+1);
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

Note that `i + a + 1 <= str.length()` is the same as `i + a < str.length()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `while` loop cycle instead of `for`:

```
 int a = 0; 
 while (a < str.length && i + a < str.length()) {
     sub = str.substring(a, i + a + 1);
     System.out.println(sub);
     a++;
 }
```

Also it is possible to replace `break` with `return` statement

Answer (score 1):

Calculate how many possible substrings there can be for a certain length. For example, length 1 = 1 substring, length 2 = 3, length 3 = 6, and so on.

Then loop for that many times. There should be a generic formula you can use for no matter how long of an input string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a break to do this task.

```
  int len = str.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     for (int j = i; j < len; j++) {
        System.out.println( str.substring( i, j + 1 ) );
     }
  }
```